# Return the last letter of three strings capitalized

Tags: java, string

I am trying to return the last letter of three user input strings and capitalize it.

If, for example, my strings are "run", "sofa" , and "computer" my output should be "NAR".

```
public static String lastLetters(String word1, String word2, String word3){

    // I tried to capitalize all the words first and input them into a string
    String x = word1.toUpperCase(); 
    String y = word2.toUpperCase();
    String z = word3.toUpperCase();

    word1 =  x.substring(x.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
    word2 =  y.substring(y.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
    word3 =  z.substring(z.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
    String lastLetters = (word1, word2, word3); 
    return lastLetters;
}
}
//The output should be
System.out.println("The last letters of the words forms the word: " + lastLetters(word1,word2,word3));
```

Comment: why are you getting the last index of a space?  What happens if the length of the string is less than 3? why not print out the values in your method?  What do you think `String lastLetters = (word1, word2, word3);` does?

Comment: thought the last index would get me the last letters of my strings. For the String lastLetters, since I stored my new "words" in the word1, word2, word3, I thought the values would get stored in it?

Comment: wrong on both counts.  Consider substring but using the length of the string minus 1 maybe.

Comment: like String word1 = x.substring(x.length()-1);?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider this answer

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String word1 = "run";
    String word2 = "sofa";
    String word3 = "computer";

    System.out.println(lastLetters (word1, word2, word3));

}

private static String lastLetters(String word1, String word2,
        String word3) {

    return (word1.substring(word1.length() -1) + 
            word2.substring(word2.length() -1) + 
            word3.substring(word3.length() -1)).toUpperCase();
}
```